# Как исправить ошибку в TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

Есть код

```
const layouts = {
  shop: NavShop,
  sites: NavSite,
  crm: NavCrm,
  company: NavCompany,
}

const layout = computed(() => layouts[route.meta.menu])
```

ругается на

```
layouts[route.meta.menu]
```

и выдает

```
 Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Comment: нужно прописать типы для `route.meta.menu`

Comment: можете подсказать что и где? я что-то голову ломаю

Comment: там где у тебя объявлено `route.meta.menu`

Comment: в роуте? или layouts[route.meta.menu]

Comment: у тебя есть значение `route.meta.menu` - у него тип `unkonwn` - тебе надо понять почему оно `unknown`, а не определенного типа. Для этого нужно посмотреть как это все объявлено.

Comment: в роуте meta: { layout: 'default', menu: 'shop'},

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135037/discussion-between-grundy-and-aslero).